# Accessing virtualbox guest from LAN

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, remote-desktop

All the tutorials and guides I have seen about accessing remote desktop in virtualbox claim that it is extremely easy yet I keep getting errors.  Every time I try to access the virtualbox client running Arch Linux I get the standard error:

> Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons: 
>   1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 
>   2) The remote
>   computer is turned off 
>   3) The remote computer is not available on the
>   network

Hence I started troubleshooting this.  First I checked that the remote access is enabled
[image]

Isn't that enabled?

Second was whether the amchine is one: well it was and I even had X running (I an at the early stages of Arch Linux installation) so that can't be the reason.

Thirdly I checked whether the computer is availabe through the network which I did my pinging the guest machine (the network adapter is on bridged mode) and since I got a response I surmised that the machine is working and at the same workgroup as the rest of my lan machines.

So to recap:
- Virtualbox settings say remote display is enabled
- The machine is on
- Machine is accessible from the network

Yet still I am unable to log in.  I have tried disabling the firewall on both the machine I am connecting from and the machine that hosts the virtualbox to no avail.

[image]

So any thoughts just what is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to connect to that IP/port with netcat or telnet to see if at least a connection can be made to that port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the **Remote Display** feature you have to connect to the *host* on port 5000 and not to the *guest*.

So try to connect to the host on port 5000.

Therefore the networksetup of the guest (wheter bridged or not) does not matter.